# InitializeComponent does not exist in current context when building WPF app for x86

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, x86

I'm getting the following error when building my WPF app on my (TFS) build server:

```
The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist the current context.
```

In Visual Studio 2013, everything builds fine. I can reproduce the error if I build it with msbuild at the command line.

The problem is with my build configuration. I don't get the error when I build for AnyCPU, but I need the x86, because that's the only way I can get an ActiveX control to work (I've tried a whole load of solutions for that, believe me).

When I create a new WPF project, I can build against x86 fine, so it must be something specific to this solution, but I can't figure out what.

Anyone had a similar experience?

**Update**

When I remove my WiX installer project from the solution, everything builds fine for x86. So WiX must have something to do with it...

Comment: I think, you have to _Update the Solution Build Configuration_ and  _Add the Build Configurations to TFSBuild.proj_ [Building WiX Projects In Team Foundation Build](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/wix_with_team_build.html)

Comment: Hard to imagine what a WiX project could have to do with an InitializeComponent() method.  I suspect you'll get somewhere by *not* messing with the Solution Platform but instead use the correct setting to force the project to run in 32-bit mode.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Compile tab > Platform target = x86.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed that does the trick. I was always under the impression that the platform you chose in the project properties was the same as the one you choose (per project) in the Solution's Configuration Manager. Apparently not. I'll have to read up on that. If you post your comment as an answer, I'd happily mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I've also had this issue and managed to fix it by adding a reference to BootstrapperCore.dll from the WixToolset SDK. No idea why, but I can reproduce and correct the error over and over again by adding and removing Wix\WixSharp references or nuget-packages from my project.